# KnockoutJS - filtering user input

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple input text element:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:valInserted,valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
```

How can I validate the user input on this element? I have a problem with creating the proper binding to port the jQuery code:

```
$('[id$="pinBox"] :text').keypress(function (e)
{
   if (!(e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) && e.keyCode != 8)
   {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: For that particular bit of validation I'm not sure I see a reason to change it. It's just rejecting keys, right? Doesn't it still work?

Comment: Yes, it works. But I'm curious how can I achieve sth like this using the KnockoutJS library, not only binding the element event by jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got it.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="validateValue:valInserted,valueUpdate:'afterkeydown',value:valInserted" />

ko.bindingHandlers.validateValue = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        viewModel.valInserted(value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    }
};
```

Comment: You are here assuming name of the value in your bindingHandler eg. valInserted.